# Failed to build wavemaker app using angular ui mode

Tags: javascript, java, html, wavemaker

I'm using Wavemaker to develop an app. For deployment, we use docker image, so I need to build the app using docker and then push the image. It works fine when I build the app using `wm` UI mode. But my build failed when I switched UI mode to `angular`.

I'm using Wavemaker 11.5.3. I use dockerfile from Wavemaker docs directly. This is the failed log
[image: failed log]

Also this is the dockerfile content

```
FROM maven:3.9.5-eclipse-temurin-11 as maven-java-node
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG=~/.m2
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/content/node
WORKDIR /usr/local/content/node
ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.1/node-v18.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz .
RUN tar -xzf node-v18.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/local/content/node/node-v18.16.1-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node \
    && ln -s /usr/local/content/node/node-v18.16.1-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm \
    && chown -R root:root /usr/local/content/node \
    && rm -fR node-v18.16.1-linux-x64.tar.gz

FROM maven-java-node as webapp-artifact
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/content/app
ADD ./ /usr/local/content/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/content/app
ARG build_profile_name
ENV profile=${build_profile_name}
RUN  mvn clean install -P${profile}

FROM tomcat:9.0.83-jdk11-temurin
COPY --from=webapp-artifact /usr/local/content/app/target/*.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

I have been searched all over the internet, but no luck